# Match all Quoted String but filter on string before quote string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression testing for all quoted strings. It's okay.

```
\"(?<InQuote>[^\"]*)\"
```

But I also ned to filter on some test before the quote. E.g. "test".. So that only those lines with the string "test" before a quote is listed.

```
aTestButton.Text("some string in qoute"); //get this
aButton.Text("some string in qoute"); //don't get this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `test.*` in front of your regular expression, i.e.

```
test.*\"(?<InQuote>[^\"]*)\"
```

If you want to match the example you provided in your question, be sure to specify the "case-insensitive" modifier on your regex search. How this is done depends on the programming language that you use.

Comment: Okay. But what if the Quote contains the "test" string. I see now that this is my problem.. hm.

Comment: @Vemund: This tests for "test" inside the quote: `\"(?<InQuote>[^\"]*test[^\"]*)\"`; you could combine both by doing `firstRegex|secondRegex`. If you want to allow "test" at *any* position in the string, it might easier to just do two checks: One which checks for "test" and the other one which checks for (and returns) the quoted content.

Comment: Thanks! I have found a test that works for me. 
^.*?test.*?\"(?<InQuote>.)*?\".*?$ 

I can also add a test to exclude test inside the quote.
^.*?test.*?\"((?<InQuote>!test).)*?\".*?$